# javascript confirm run php file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript confirm box and if the user clicks OK then I want to run a php script. Not sure on how to do this. Below is the javascript code for the confirm box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function val_name()
 {
        var namePattern = /^[A-Za-z]{3,25}$/;
    if( !namePattern.test(document.upload.fn.value))
            alert("Enter valid first name");

    if( !namePattern.test(document.upload.ln.value))
        alert("Enter valid last name");


        var x=document.forms["upload"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
        {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
        }


    else if
        (confirm("Are you sure you want to add this driver?")== true)
        {
        onClick = 'add_driver.php';
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: use an ajax call to the add_driver.php

Comment: what would I search for? Never used AJAX before.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
 window.location.href='add_driver.php';
```

Comment: I tried the window.location.href='add_driver.php'; and that didn't work. What should I look up to do this with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'add_driver.php';
```

That will take you to the page, causing the script to run. If you didn't want to go to the page but just wanted it to run, look into jQuery and using its AJAX functions.

Comment: What should I look up to do this with AJAX?

Comment: never used JQuery or AJAX before. What would I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code to call the add_driver.php

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //here you can put some code to execute if the call to add_driver.php was ok
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","add_driver.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not even sure what to do with this code. Never used AJAX before. I thought what I wanted was easy. In the confirm pop-up if the user clicked OK I wanted to call the add_driver.php with includes a couple of php files (using includes - connect to mysql - add driver - upload photo and close mysql. I was hoping it was just being able to call the php file.